# Messy &quot returned from Rails 3 controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, quotes, html-safe

On my Rails 3 app controller I have the following code:

```
array = []
Location.all.each{|x|array<<x.city.html_safe}
@data_dump = array
```

In the Rails console it looks nice and clean:

```
["Littelside", "Tessmouth"]
```

In my view the @data_dump object gets encoded:

```
[&quot;Littelside&quot;, &quot;Tessmouth&quot;]
```

How do you clean this mess up? I want my object in view, to return as the object does in terminal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your view code. And it looks like everything is fine.

Comment: It looks like in your view is calling `to_s` on the array, and then html encoding it. Do you want `to_s` or to use the contents of the array somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

```
<%=raw @data_dump %>
```