# Keeping a Sinatra app light: Displaying a raw array without loading ActionView

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'd like to make sure that my array stays like this in the view:

```
["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]
```

Instead of being converted to this:

```
[&quot;Tue&quot;, &quot;Wed&quot;, &quot;Thu&quot;, &quot;Fri&quot;, &quot;Sat&quot;, &quot;Sun&quot;, &quot;Mon&quot;, &quot;Tue&quot;]
```

The code in my erb file is for a highcharts graph:

```
categories: <%= @days %>,
```

In Rails, I have used the [`raw`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) method:

After following advice from [Messy &quot returned from Rails 3 controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131347/messy-quot-returned-from-rails-3-controller-to-view) and [Use ruby array for a javascript array in erb. Escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561430/use-ruby-array-for-a-javascript-array-in-erb-escaping-quotes)

However, loading all of ActionView to use one method seems to defeat the object of Sinatra.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you markup be escaped anyway? Sinatra doesn't do it by default.

Comment: "After following advice …" is an incomplete sentence. What did you do after following the advice in those questions?

Comment: Is the array defined in the template (I'm assuming ERB) or in the route? Have you tried `["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"].inspect` ?

Comment: I would like it to be escaped, I'm wondering what's the best method.

Comment: In ERB, thanks for taking a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get some escaping on the array right now, but this is what I put in an ERB view:

```
<% array = ["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"] %>

<p><%= array.inspect %></p>
<p><%= array.inspect.gsub(/"/, '\"') %></p>
```

and this was the output:

> ["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"]
>
> [\"Tue\", \"Wed\", \"Thu\", \"Fri\", \"Sat\", \"Sun\", \"Mon\",
>   \"Tue\"]

But the real question is "How do I get data from Sinatra into a javascript function?"

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  get "/array", :provides => :json do
    content_type :json
    ["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"].to_json
  end

end
```

and then call it via some jQuery (or whichever library you would prefer) compiled from coffeescript, of course :)

```
$.getJSON "/array", (res) ->
  # do something with the result
```

Which means:

- you don't need to worry about escaping
- the jQuery takes care of parsing the JSON response so you've just to work with an object
- it's easier to test
- you've got an API set up with a web app calling against it (i.e. the Sinatra way not the Rails way)
- and you'll be doing something more similar to other people which will make getting help easier.